# python how to get string form list value

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
```

which is list of string.

Now I want to iterate in such way that I get `abc` . How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"".join(a)
```

should do it for you.

or

```
 "".join(map(str, a))
```

if all elements are not strings

Comment: Also use  " ".join(map(str, a)) if the list does not contain all strings.

Comment: @wolfsgang added thanx

Answer (score 0):

Another slightly less pythonic way:

```
string = ''
for letter in a:
    string += letter
```

Comment: Its also very inefficient for large strings.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to one mentioned by vks. This assumes that the list contains elements which are str or support the + operator in a way that it aligns with the semantics of appending.

```
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, ['a','b','c'])
```